# How can I landscape my laptop screen, with a LCD screen

Tags: display

I could not figure out exactly what I needed, so I made a picture. Currently I cannot figure out what cords I need (or for converting.)[image: Diagram]

Anyone know what cords and converter things needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your LCD screen has a VGA input. You will need a [HDMI to VGA Male to Female Adapter](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/belkin-hdmi-to-vga-adapter-black-white/1740039.p?id=1219062507184&skuId=1740039) (maybe you need a longer cord). Once you have this hooked up, right click on your desktop background, and select "Screen resolution". You should see both displays on the screen (if not, make sure they are both on and connected). You can click on the black box's that represent your monitors and adjust accordingly.